# .NET RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter Class - Exception "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: c#, encryption

I tried to split up the sample for .NET RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter Class from https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/8kkwbeez(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx into 2 console apps (Alice, Bob) using a common class named KeyExchange. This class contains two methods:
GenerateEncryptedSessionKeyAndIV: runs on Alice, encrypts the session key, and for test purposes decrypts it. 
ProcessEncryptedSessionKeyAndIV: runs on Bob, fails to decrypt the session key with Exception "The parameter is incorrect". Although the byte arrays look correct. Please help.

```
       public KeyExchange()
    {
        rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();    // asymmetric encryption/decryption
        aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();       // symmetric encryption/decryption
    }

    public byte[] PublicKey
    {
        get { return rsaKey.ExportCspBlob(false); }   // used by partner who wants to send secret session key
        set { rsaKey.ImportCspBlob(value); }          // used by partner who receives secret session key
    }

    public void GenerateEncryptedSessionKeyAndIV(out byte[] iv, out byte[] encryptedSessionKey)
    {
        iv = aes.IV; // Gets the initialization vector (IV) for the symmetric algorithm.

        // Encrypt the session key
        RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter keyFormatter = new RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter(rsaKey);  // Initializes a new instance of the RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter class with the specified key.
        encryptedSessionKey = keyFormatter.CreateKeyExchange(aes.Key, typeof(Aes));         // Create and return the encrypted key exchange data

        // test only: the next 2 lines are to prove that the secret key can be obtained from the the encrypted key exchange data here on Alice,
        // the same code failes executed on Bob (see method ProcessEncryptedSessionKeyAndIV)
        RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter keyDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter(rsaKey);
        byte[] helper = keyDeformatter.DecryptKeyExchange(encryptedSessionKey);
    }

    public void ProcessEncryptedSessionKeyAndIV(byte[] iv, byte[] encryptedSessionKey)
    {
         aes.IV = iv; // Sets the initialization vector (IV) for the symmetric algorithm.

        // Decrypt the session key, Create a KeyExchangeDeformatter
        RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter keyDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter(rsaKey);
        // obtain the secret key (32 bytes) from from the encrypted key exchange data (128 bytes)
        aes.Key = keyDeformatter.DecryptKeyExchange(encryptedSessionKey);  // this results in CryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect. 
    }
```

Comment: A stack trace would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, psychic debugging time.

- You have Alice construct one of these and call `GenerateEncryptedSessionKeyAndIV()`.  She sends that value, and the value of `PublicKey` (which shouldn't be a property because it does a lot more work than you want happening in a debugger every time you hit F10).
- You have Bob construct one of these and assign `PublicKey`, then call `ProcessEncryptedSessionKeyAndIV`.

The exception is because Bob doesn't have the private key, so he can't decrypt.

You're doing KeyExchange, which suggests you're online, which suggests you should just use TLS and call it a day. If you're offline you want KeyAgreement (Diffie-Hellman, or EC Diffie-Hellman).

Nevertheless, the right way is

- Private-key-holder sends their public key, preferably as a certificate
- Other party verifies the public key (which is much easier when it's a certificate... nigh on impossible if it's just key data)
- Other party generates some data to hide
- Other party encrypts the data using the received public key
- Other party sends the encrypted data back
- Private-key-holder decrypts the data (with the private key)
- Now both sides know what the data was (which could be a key, could be a key+algorithm, could be an input into a KDF, ...)

For KeyExchange these roles are usually called Server (private-key-holder) and Client (other party).